# Flutter App Not Working on MacOS -> Exception: Error running pod install when launching MacOS app. No errors when run outside of MacOS

Tags: flutter, macos, cocoapods, pod-install

I get this error message when trying to launch on macOS.

I have no issues when launching with iOS simulator, android emulator, or chrome web app.

I work on an M1 Mac and my terminal launches through rosetta.

I have manually removed and reinstalled the pods in the iOS folder within the flutter app.

Please help. Below is the debug console within VSCode when trying to run the app as well as the results from flutter doctor -v.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `FlutterMacOS` from `Flutter/ephemeral`
    -> Fetching podspec for `audio_session` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/audio_session/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `audioplayers` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/audioplayers/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `device_info_plus_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/device_info_plus_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_secure_storage_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/flutter_secure_storage_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `just_audio` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/just_audio/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `package_info_plus_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/package_info_plus_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `pdfx` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/pdfx/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `printing` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/printing/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `wakelock_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/wakelock_macos/macos`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "just_audio":
      In Podfile:
        just_audio (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/just_audio/macos`)
    Specs satisfying the `just_audio (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/just_audio/macos`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
Exception: Error running pod install
Exited
```

**Flutter Doctor -v below:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm (Rosetta),
    locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.2 at /Users/jackestes/Flutter/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cd41fdd495 (7 days ago), 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
    • Engine revision f15f824b57
    • Dart version 2.17.3
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jackestes/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at:
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bi
      n/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 18.0.1.1+0)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Coding/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Coding/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.1.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/Coding/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Coding/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm
      (Rosetta)
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Did you add  <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/> in Info.plist ??

Answer (score 1):

In PodFile uncomment platform version and change its value to 11 or 12

Answer (score 1):

What do you have set as the deployment target for macOS?
You need to increase the version inside Podfile as shown below.
[image: Podfile]

Answer (score 0):

Delete Podfile.lock,
and run pod install